# How to integrate Crashlytics into an iOS framework project?

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am building a new iOS framework and would like to integrate Crashlytics in it. Using Fabric.io Mac tool I clicked on `+New App` and selected my iOS framework Xcode project. However, in the next screen ("Initialize the SDK") I get the following error:

> This Xcode project does not have any Mac or iOS targets

Well yes - my framework target Bundle OS code is `FMWK` and not the usual `AAPL` of an app.

My question: has anyone managed to integrate Crashlytics into an iOS framework project? Is it possible, and how this can be done?

Comment: I would love to know how to do this as well. In my case I have two projects in the same workspace: an app and a framework project that's used by said app. I would like crashlytics to inform me of crashes that happen in my framework. Right now it just tells me that a crash happened in the framework and in what method but not on what line.

Answer (score 1):

Crashlytics is for the ios app crash logs for the developers to immediately find  crashes in the application. It is not a development framework and integrates  Crashlytics in the framework building.

In other words, Crashlytics will integrate only in the xcode project of a  either Mac OS X application or ios mobile app.

Comment: Thanks to point out. But I'm curious about is there any tools can be used to easily collect crash log by frameworks developers?

Comment: Easiest tool is Crashlytics. Most of the people using this for crash logs. because it gives step by step crash to regenerate it.