# iOS Swift: Send log information to iOS app from iOS framework

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I am trying to find out how to send logging information from my iOS framework to my iOS app. Inside my iOS app, I have the Crashlytics setup, and would like to use the `Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)` whenever I get some logs from the app as well as my iOS framework.

I read through multiple answers mentioning Crashlytics can be initialized only once in the App and it is not recommended to initialize again in the framework. (for example [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155649/how-to-integrate-crashlytics-into-an-ios-framework-target)), [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31960333/how-to-integrate-crashlytics-into-an-ios-framework-project), [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755152/can-i-add-crashlytics-to-an-ios-library))

Does anyone have a working solution for such a requirement?

**EDIT 1 (adding more code from my framework where I need to get the errors from)**

```
public final class MyAppSession {

    public fileprivate(set) var isValid: Bool = false

    let itemKey = MyAppSession.MyAppKeychainAccount
    let keychainAccessGroupName = MyAppConfigured?.keyChainGroup

    /**
     Attempts to restore a locally stored session.
     */
    public static func savedSession() -> MyAppSession? {

        do {

            let itemKey = MyAppSession.MyAppKeychainAccount
            let keychainAccessGroupName = MyAppConfigured?.keyChainGroup

            let queryLoad: [String: AnyObject] = [
                kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                kSecAttrAccount as String: itemKey as AnyObject,
                kSecReturnData as String: kCFBooleanTrue,
                kSecMatchLimit as String: kSecMatchLimitOne,
                kSecAttrAccessGroup as String: keychainAccessGroupName as AnyObject
            ]

            var result: AnyObject?

            let resultCodeLoad = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &result) {
                SecItemCopyMatching(queryLoad as CFDictionary, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
            }

            if resultCodeLoad == noErr {
                if let result = result as? Data {
                    if let arrayFromData = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: result) as? NSDictionary {
                        // Found successfully
                        return MyAppSession(accessToken: (arrayFromData["accessToken"] as? String)!, refreshToken: (arrayFromData["refreshToken"] as? String)!)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                MyApp.log("No Keychain elements present.", logLevel: .verbose)
                MyAppLogger.sendLogs(message: "Logger Test. No Keychain elements present.")
            }

            let keychainData = try Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount(userAccount: MyAppSession.MyAppKeychainAccount)
            if let accessToken = keychainData?[MyAppSession.accessTokenKeychainKey] as? String,
                let refreshToken = keychainData?[MyAppSession.refreshTokenKeychainKey] as? String {

                MyApp.log("Restored saved session.", logLevel: .verbose)

                return MyAppSession(accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken)

            }
            else {
                return nil
            }

        }
        catch {
            return nil
        }

    }

    init?(accessToken: String, refreshToken: String) {

        // Save credentials to the keychain.
        do {

            try Locksmith.updateData(
                data: [MyAppSession.accessTokenKeychainKey: accessToken as AnyObject, MyAppSession.refreshTokenKeychainKey: refreshToken as AnyObject],
                forUserAccount: MyAppSession.MyAppKeychainAccount)

            if let configuration = MyAppConfigured {
                if configuration.keyChainGroup == "" {
                    let valueData = [MyAppSession.accessTokenKeychainKey: accessToken as AnyObject, MyAppSession.refreshTokenKeychainKey: refreshToken as AnyObject]

                    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: valueData)

                    let queryAdd: [String: AnyObject] = [
                        kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                        kSecAttrAccount as String: itemKey as AnyObject,
                        kSecValueData as String: data as AnyObject,
                        kSecAttrAccessible as String: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked
                    ]

                    let resultCode = SecItemAdd(queryAdd as CFDictionary, nil)

                    if resultCode != noErr {
                        MyApp.log("Keychain groupname empty: \(resultCode)", logLevel: .verbose)
                    }
                    else {
                        MyApp.log("KeyChain Saving Success", logLevel: .verbose)
                    }

                }

                else {
                    let valueData = [MyAppSession.accessTokenKeychainKey: accessToken as AnyObject, MyAppSession.refreshTokenKeychainKey: refreshToken as AnyObject]

                    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: valueData)

                    let queryAdd: [String: AnyObject] = [
                        kSecClass as String: kSecClassGenericPassword,
                        kSecAttrAccount as String: itemKey as AnyObject,
                        kSecValueData as String: data as AnyObject,
                        kSecAttrAccessible as String: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked,
                        kSecAttrAccessGroup as String: keychainAccessGroupName as AnyObject
                    ]

                    let resultCode = SecItemAdd(queryAdd as CFDictionary, nil)

                    if resultCode != noErr {
                        MyApp.log("Error saving to Keychain: \(resultCode)", logLevel: .verbose)
                    }
                    else {
                        MyApp.log("KeyChain Saving Success", logLevel: .verbose)
                    }
                }
            }

            isValid = true

            MyApp.log("Created new session.")

        }
        catch {
            return nil
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to delegate the logging of the error to your application. This makes it much more flexible.

For example:

```
protocol MyFrameworkErrorHandlingDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didReceiveError(_ error: Error)
}
```

Then in your application you can create a default extension of this

```
extension MyFrameworkErrorHandlingDelegate {
     func didReceiveError(_ error: Error) {
         Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)
     }
}
```

The problem with this approach is deciding where to use it or where to assign the delegate and this depends on what your framework does and how your application uses the framework.

**EDIT:**

**Disclaimer:** This won't be the most efficient way to do this, but it would be the most straight forward.

```
protocol MyFrameworkErrorHandlingDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didReceiveError(_ error: Error)
}

class MyAppLogger {

    static var delegate: MyFrameworkErrorHandlingDelegate?

    static func log(_ error: Error) {
        delegate?.didReceiveError(error)
    }
}

class AppDelegate: UIApplicationDelegate, MyFrameworkErrorHandlingDelegate
```

later in your AppDelegate

```
MyAppLogger.delegate = self
```

Comment: on flexibility point of view the approach is really nice. I can't disagree with you on the problem though. I am not able to deice where to assign the delegate. Will take this as a start to the implementation.
Now, when I am using the MyFrameworkErrorHandlingDelegate, I get "Use of undeclared type 'error' ". Can you please elaborate on this if possible?

Comment: I would like to use the logs/errors that come from my MyAppSession where I try to save and retrieve credentials from keychain (for example). I added my code in my question. Could you take a look at it please?

Comment: Oh sorry that was just a typo, should be Error

Comment: So `MyAppLogger` is using static methods, if you had a static property for the delegate you could assign the AppDelegate as the delegate

Comment: Yes, I was too quick to ask before I realized it should be Error. Sorry, I didn't understand on what you mentioned about assigning AppDelegate as delegate

Comment: I updated my answer and provided an example of what i mean

Comment: Thank you! I have setup almost the same approach on my project at the moment, I believe this is the way to start!!

Comment: Thank you, if this is the solution you are going for could you accept the answer so that it shows as resolved. good luck with the project

Comment: Accepted! The logging is going well but only the first 'Crashlytics.sharedInstance().recordError(error)' is reflected on the Dashboard. Anything after that is not being shown.

Comment: strange, if you put a breakpoint in is it calling it multiple times?

Comment: yes, it is. It shows all logs that I wanted to send to Crashlytics when on breakpoint. Initially, I thought it was only an issue with a simulator. But it happens on Devices as well.

Answer (score 0):

just create the instance in appdelegate, and use them in your frameworks. Do not instantiate Crashlytics in the framework, just use them there.